# No template when I create a new project on android studio

Tags: android, macos, visual-studio, templates

So I downloaded yesterday visual studio and I wanted to create a new android project in Android studio but I couldn't find any template instead I have frameworks and libraries to choose from (as you can see from the screenshot).[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you downloaded wrong editor. It's `IntelliJ IDEA` instead of `Android studio`. Please refer to this link for android studio

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: I have deleted the old version and installed the one that you did send me as  a reference but I still have the same issue. as well the SDK manager doesn't appear. So I can't install or update any SDK version.